# How to measure the length of the Confidence interval?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have two samples, blue male crab (BM) and orange male crab (OM). The standard deviation of the BM's and OM's carapace width is 8.36. I need to contruct a 94% CI for the pop. mean of the carapace width of BM and OM. Then measure the length of the interval. Blue male crabs u= 36.81/ OM u= 37.19. population n=200 u=36.41

```
conf.level <- 0.94
n<-50
z <- qt((1+conf.level)/2,df=n-1)
z
[1] 1.676551
sd <- 8.36
se <- sd(Height)/sqrt(n)
```

I am stuck here and can't get past this part.

Comment: The lower and upper CI limits are simply `mean(Height) - z * se` and `mean(Height) + z * se`.

Comment: You want a *94%* CI? Not a 90% one? Or a 95% one? I think I have never before seen a 94% CI. (Apart from that, [@MauritsEvers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311575/how-to-measure-the-length-of-the-confidence-interval#comment591952_311575) is completely right.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa as CI is arbitrary, perhaps 94% works better in that it got your attention ;)

Comment: @ssp3nc3r: that's because I routinely run CV searches for "94% CI", "$R^2$ of 1.24" or "$\text{var}X = -0.3$" and similar.

Comment: Since the length is found by subtracting the limits of the confidence interval, and surely subtraction in `R` is not problematic, what are you trying to ask for help on, exactly?